# Is there more efficient way to write this SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Is there a way to write this more efficiently in Postgres?
I will be re-using this in several other queries.
Table A is large, table B is 1/3 of the size of A, C is very small.

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3
FROM A a
         LEFT JOIN B b on a.ref_id = b.id
         LEFT JOIN C c on b.other_ref_id = c.id
WHERE a.field1 IN (...)
```

The execution plan shows large value for `loops` for the 1st LEFT JOIN.

Explain plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1002.62..1290550.84 rows=856452 width=74) (actual time=0.495..1554.401 rows=850836 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=4022375 read=234277
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2.62..1203905.64 rows=356855 width=74) (actual time=0.263..1441.760 rows=283612 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (b.other_ref_id = c.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=4022375 read=234277
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.13..1202967.39 rows=356855 width=44) (actual time=0.145..1402.434 rows=283612 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=4022316 read=234277
              ->  Parallel Index Scan using some_existing_idx on A a  (cost=0.69..785157.53 rows=356855 width=30) (actual time=0.101..731.991 rows=283612 loops=3)
                    Index Cond: (field1 = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}'::bigint[]))
                    Buffers: shared hit=632106 read=225426
              ->  Index Scan using b_pkey on B b  (cost=0.44..1.17 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=850836)
                    Index Cond: (id = a.ref_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3390210 read=8851
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.22..1.22 rows=22 width=34) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=22 loops=3)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
              Buffers: shared hit=3
              ->  Seq Scan on C c  (cost=0.00..1.22 rows=22 width=34) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=22 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 5.382 ms
Execution Time: 1581.816 ms
```

Comment: Be sure you have indexes on all the `join` columns.

Comment: indexes exist for all except for `a.ref_id` which has a FK to `b.id`

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -added, please see the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested loop left join between `a` and `b` is probably the most efficient method here. There are 850000 loops, but each of these executions takes only 0.002 milliseconds, which makes a grand total of about 1.9 seconds. This is done by three workers in parallel, so the actual time is about 0.6 seconds.

This, together with the 0.7 seconds from the parallel index scan on `a` makes up the execution time.

The alternative would have been to perform a hash join between `a` and `b`, which would have required a sequential scan on `b` and a large hash. Either the sequential scan would have been more expensive, or `work_mem` was configured too small to contain the resulting hash.

The only chance for improvement is to raise `work_mem` and see if execution becomes slightly faster that way.

To test if my analysis is correct, try to

```
SET enable_nestloop = off;
```

and then run the query again. If this makes execution slower, PostgreSQL has done the right thing.

Comment: Yes, setting `enable_nestloop` does slow the execution. Where do you see the number of workers is three?

Comment: The 2 "workers launched" and the backend process itself.